# iOS opening animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I am currently executing my own version of this opening animation

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

The animation runs perfectly however once the default.png disappears and my animation starts the UITabBar and the UIPicker I have loaded in the first view are sitting above my animation when it plays.. I am wondering how to make sure this animation plays above everything.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the animation, call:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:basketTop];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:basketBottom];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:napkinTop];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:napkinBottom];
```

This basically pulls those 4 objects to the front of the view, so they are on top of everything else. You might need to play around with the order in which you bring the 4 to the front.

Comment: I put this above the code in the viewDidLoad method and it didnt work :( But to be honest I think there is a deeper issue with what I am working on atm as I had a default.png splash screen that I deleted from my project but every time I build it keeps loading itself onto the app..

Comment: cleared up all the problems but still it is still not allowing loading the images above the other stuff when it plays the animation.

Comment: Try using `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:toolBar];` and repeat for everything the appears on top.

Comment: That worked perfectly for the picker.. (you have to addsubview:picker first then call sendSubviewToBack for this to work :) but its perfect) I just have to figure out where to declare my tool bar as I think it was all set up in my interface builder with the iphone template..

Comment: So looking through my code and the tab bar is declared inside my delegate **- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions** method so I am not sure what I will be able to do to get this animation to play over the tabbar.. will keep looking through the documentation and let you know if I stumble across anything.

Comment: `IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar` in the `@interface` (in the `.h` file) of the same class as the IB document you put it in.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the z-order you should check that the view you are trying to animate has the proper size, otherwise it can't possibly cover the whole screen. And of course check your view's superview - if the superview covers only the area between UITabBar and UIPicker it won't cover them, ever.

Answer (score 0):

In your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you could present a modal view controller and perform your animation(s) inside of it then remove the controller.

Or you could perform those animations on the window.

Since the controller's view is inside a a tab bar controller, its view doesn't cover the tab bar and therefore cannot show over it.